# vscodeでphpコードの編集時に、カラー構文がおかしくなる

Tags: php, vscode

vscodeでphpのコード編集時に以下のようなコードを入力すると、以降のカラー構文がおかしくなってしまいます。

```
$a = " AND a[".$val['idx']."]";
```

これは不具合でしょうか？
それとも、phpコードを編集するのに、初期状態からなにか設定や追加する必要があるでしょうか？
どなたか、何かご存知であれば、お助けください。

Comment: 私の環境でも再現しました。VS Code の [PHP 向けシンタックスハイライト](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/e5c3c10853a8cfff46369075223850d7af3fe5d6/extensions/php/syntaxes/php.tmLanguage.json)は Atom の [PHP 向けシンタックスハイライト](https://github.com/atom/language-php/blob/955cc83c4cc9a9b5c60c5c3cc04b4be1c1bd3ca1/grammars/php.cson)から自動生成しているのですが、Atom だとこのバグが出ませんでした。VS Code 側の[この issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40564) と同様、VS Code 側のバグに見えます。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
AND や ORなどの文字列が絡むと、シンタックスハイライトがおかしくなってしまうバグがありそうですね。